# Splitting the textarea and storing in array then post every element to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm working with firebase using pure javascript. But my problem is when I upload the elements of array, it has no value and it only loop once. And what I want to do is split the text area and store it in array and for every loop it will add a new document to my collection in firebase

This is my javascript code. Thanks in advance

```
var area = document.getElementById("instruction");
var lines = area.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
lines.forEach(instrct =>  {
                let i = 0;
                db.collection('recipeInstruction').add({
                    instruction: instrct,
                    order: i + 1,
                    recipeId: docRef.id,
                    status: false,
                    userId: user.uid,
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(instrct);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.message);
                });
                ++i;
            });
```

Comment: So the problem here is that after the code finish running,there is no record in firebase collection? Or the lines array only loops once ?

Comment: Same sir. only the instruction field in firebase have no record and only loop once

Comment: Thats weird cause if there is a document, the instruction field should be avaliable.Unless the array contain empty string. console log the lines.

Comment: Yes it is available sir. But the value is ' '. So I try to console log the array first and its working. But if I try the code above, the value is ' '.

Comment: I can't still point out the issue but lets try using Promise.all. I know promise and foreach don't work well together.

Comment: Can you check the 1st line of code sir? Hehe I think that's the problem. Because I try to add it as array and I try using Promise.all but its not working. Its still blank

Comment: The document field in my collection is instruction: []

Comment: Meaning lines is an empty array?? Console log area and lines and add the value here as comment.

Comment: This where things complicated. When I console log the lines the array will show up. If only I can show you the picture. So I console log the lines and the value is

```post.js:44 (2) ["foo", "bar"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try using Promise.all to make the call to firebase.

```
var area = document.getElementById("instruction");
var lines = area.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
const promises = [];
let i = 0;
lines.forEach(instrct =>  {
  i += 1;
  promises.push(db.collection('recipeInstruction').add({
   instruction: instrct,
   order: i,
   recipeId: docRef.id,
   status: false,
   userId: user.uid,
  }));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(results => { 
 console.log({lines, msg: "sucess"});
 console.log(results.map(r => r.id));
}).catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: Sir the value in results show the prints the array but it not add in the database

Comment: recipeInstruction

Comment: When I console log the array. Its printing but when I add it to firebase. The value is ' '.

Comment: Try to attach image to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is console image
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeHhH.png)

this is the firebase
[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr0k4.png)

Comment: I change the success in your code in console log to lines to check the array

Comment: The lines is [""] ?

Comment: Yes sir. its blank

Comment: ```https://meet.google.com/mcq-mgic-wyv``` this is the link sir